# Husky Description Launch Has No Wheels

Tags: rviz, urdf, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,

I am working on a robot that uses a husky base but also has a lot of other custom attached components.  I am being asked to create a urdf for it.  I learned about urdfs through the tutorials and ran the description.launch file provided by the husky package that is supposed to publish the robot model.

Upon opening rviz, I saw that there were no transforms for the wheels.  I looked in the urdf, and there is indeed no reference to the wheels.  There is another urdf which creates the wheels, but there is no obvious connection between the two files.  The launch file only runs base.urdf, not wheel.urdf.

I want to use the husky materials as a base to begin making my robot's urdf.  I don't understand why these files are not connected, however, or what I am supposed to do to load the whole model.

Could someone please explain why the package was made so that the launch file only loads the base without any mention of the wheels?  Also, how do I incorporate the wheels so that all transforms are published and the model and be seen in rviz?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/95796/husky-description-launch-has-no-wheels/) by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2013-10-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

wheel.urdf is included in base.urdf, but the husky_description launchfile doesn't start any joint state publisher which has the necessary transforms. This is because you might want to publish the joint states from real data, from a simulator, or just faking it with joint_state_publisher, and husky_description is a dependency of all of those use cases.

If you'd like a basic example suitable for visualization, check out the launchfiles in husky_viz (https://github.com/husky/husky_viz/blob/hydro-devel/launch/view_model.launch)

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2013-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on 2013-12-07**:
Thanks Ryan!